# How can I start a jquery function on clicking a button and on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a function that sends some data from a form using Ajax.

To prevent the form from posting it without Ajax I use `preventDefault();` this also stops the form from submitting when pressing `enter`.

How can I make sure the function below is started when clicking the button (as it is now) and also when pressing the `enter` button?

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click",".login-button",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    loginform = $(".login-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:"includes/inloggen.php",
     data:({loginform: loginform}),
     success:function(data){
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);

         var arrayspot = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
             var status = obj[i].status;
             var field = obj[i].field;
             if(status == 'error'){
                    var message = obj[i].message;
                    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).parent().addClass('invalid-input');
                    var errorveld = $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).parent();
                    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).parent().next('.inputerror').remove();
                    errorveld.after('<div class="inputerror"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> ' + message + '</div>');
             }else if(status == 'success'){
                    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).parent().next('.inputerror').remove();
                    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).parent().removeClass('invalid-input');
             }
             var arrayspot = parseInt(i);
         }
         if(obj[arrayspot].totalstatus == 'error'){
             $( "#loginresult" ).removeClass('positiveresult');
             $( "#loginresult" ).show().empty().append( obj[arrayspot].totalmessage );
         }else if(obj[arrayspot].totalstatus == 'success'){
             window.location.replace("https://website.nl/new/");
         }
     }
 });
});
```

I've tried copying the entire function but this time start it on enter press but there must be another way with fewer lines of code? Without sending double ajax requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this behaviour for free when you have your controls contained within a `<form>`. From the context of your code using `serialize()` it appears this is already the case. As such you can simply amend your logic to listen for the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click` of the submit button. Try this:

```js
$("body").on("submit", ".login-form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginform = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "includes/inloggen.php",
    data: {
      loginform: loginform
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);

      var arrayspot = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var status = obj[i].status;
        var field = obj[i].field;
        var $errorveld = $('input[name="' + field + '"]').parent();

        if (status == 'error') {
          var message = obj[i].message;
          $errorveld.addClass('invalid-input');
          $errorveld.next('.inputerror').remove();
          $errorveld.after('<div class="inputerror"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> ' + message + '</div>');
        } else if (status == 'success') {
          $errorveld.next('.inputerror').remove();
          $errorveld.removeClass('invalid-input');
        }
        var arrayspot = parseInt(i);
      }
      if (obj[arrayspot].totalstatus == 'error') {
        $("#loginresult").removeClass('positiveresult').show().empty().append(obj[arrayspot].totalmessage);
      } else if (obj[arrayspot].totalstatus == 'success') {
        window.location.replace("https://website.nl/new/");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that I tidied the logic a little by removing the unnecessary `()` around the `data` property and also caching the `$('input[name="' + field + '"]').parent()` selector.

Finally, if the MIME type of the response is set correctly you shouldn't need to manually call `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code. But pressing enter when focusing an input inside the form does nothing, and the form also stopped submitting when pressing the button. Edit: nevermind I had a button instead of an input type submit. Thanks it works now!